# Angular, HttpClient, subscribe do not catch the error when 401

Tags: angular

I have something strange with my code.
I have this in my service, very basic, a simple httpClient get... When the API returns as status **401**, I am expecting that it goes into the error... But it does not. In my console, I only have the 'complete'. When the API returns the status 200, it does well in the 'next'
Any Idea?

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
...
  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private configService: ConfigService
  ) {}

  getUserDetails() {
    console.log('AuthService.getUserDetails');
    return this.httpClient
      .get<UserDetails>(this.configService.getModuleCoreAPi('users.details'))
      .subscribe({
        next: (ud) => {
          console.log('next', ud);
          this.userInfos.next(ud);
        },
        error: (error) => {
          console.log('error', error);
        },
        complete: () => console.log('complete'),
      });
  }
...
```

UPDATE 1:
This is not working either

```
  getUserDetails() {
    console.log('AuthService.getUserDetails');
    this.httpClient
      .get<UserDetails>(this.configService.getModuleCoreAPi('users.details'))
      .pipe(
        catchError((err) => {
          throw 'error in source. Details: ' + err;
        })
      )
      .subscribe(
        (ud) => {
          console.log('next', ud);
          this.userInfos.next(ud);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }
```

nor

```
  getUserDetails() {
    console.log('AuthService.getUserDetails');
    this.httpClient
      .get<UserDetails>(this.configService.getModuleCoreAPi('users.details'))
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          throw 'error in source. Details: ' + err;
        })
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: (ud) => {
          console.log('next', ud);
          this.userInfos.next(ud);
        },
        error: (err) => console.log(err),
      });
  }
```

Update 2
If I force the API to return the **500** status code, it passes as expected into the error

Comment: Do you have any interceptors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I forgot about the interceptor that is enabled and catching the 401 status code... Need to rest ;)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use rxjs catchError() for this.

```
this.httpClient
  .get<UserDetails>(this.configService.getModuleCoreAPi('users.details'))
  .pipe(catchError((error) => console.log(error))
  .subscribe((ud) => this.userInfos.next(ud));
```

Comment: I tried too without success..

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone else. There is another issue that can cause this.

I was having the same problem - subscribe not catching an http error. Ugh I have written this same code a zillion times but this time I had a slip of the paren.

Here's what I was doing:

```
this.httpProviderService.someHttpRequest(postObject)
  .subscribe(
    (response:any) => {
      resolve(response); 
    }),                        // The paren is in the wrong place
    (error:any) => {
      reject(error); 
  };
```

It looked good to me - but on closer inspection you will see that the closing paren is in the wrong place. This puts the error callback outside the scope of the subscribe.

The correct way is as follows:

```
this.httpProviderService.someHttpRequest(postObject)
   .subscribe(
     (response:any) => {
       resolve(response); 
     },                            // comma here
   (error:any) => {
     reject(error); 
   });                             // closing paren here
```

Answer (score -1):

you are destructuring the first parameter returned from "subscribe" method. Remove the first curly braces:

```
.subscribe(
        (ud) => {
          console.log('next', ud);
          this.userInfos.next(ud);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('error', error);
        },
        () => console.log('complete')
      );
```

Comment: I have done this following the deprecation,  https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments